# RecyclerView duplicates data multiple times

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm developing a timetable application and I have a fragment in it, which displays the users subjects and lessons in a RecyclerView, like this:

[image]

It works fine, but only for the first time. The moment I open the fragment for the second time (or just simply reload it) I get this weird bug: It starts filling in random circles with that blue-ish color as if there were lessons on that particular day. For example.: Let's say the user added two subjects, Calculus I and Databases, and a lesson to Databases on Wednesday. As soon as the fragment gets opened for the second time, there'll be a filled-in circle next to Calculus I's Wednesday as well.

I think there must be a problem somewhere in the SubjectsViewHolder class, but just in case I missed something, here's the whole RecyclerView's adapter file:

```
// Each constant value represents a view type
private const val VIEW_TYPE_NOT_EMPTY = 0
private const val VIEW_TYPE_EMPTY = 1

/**
 * A [RecyclerView.Adapter] subclass.
 * This class serves as an adapter for RecyclerViews
 * which were created to display lessons.
 *
 * @property subjectsList An [ArrayList] containing all [Subject] objects to display
 * @property lessonsList An [ArrayList] containing lessons of subjects
 * @property listener Fragments that use this class must implement [OnSubjectClickListener]
 */
class SubjectsRecyclerViewAdapter(
    private var subjectsList: ArrayList<Subject>?,
    private var lessonsList: ArrayList<Lesson>?,
    private val listener: OnSubjectClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SubjectsRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities/fragments that contain
     * this RecyclerViewAdapter to allow an interaction in this class to be
     * communicated to the activity/fragment.
     */
    interface OnSubjectClickListener {
        fun onSubjectClick(subject: Subject)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return when (viewType) {
            VIEW_TYPE_EMPTY -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.no_subject_list_item, parent, false)
                EmptySubjectViewHolder(view)
            }
            VIEW_TYPE_NOT_EMPTY -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.subject_list_items, parent, false)
                SubjectViewHolder(view)
            }
            else -> throw IllegalStateException("Couldn't recognise the view type")
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val list = subjectsList
        val lessonsList = lessonsList
        when (getItemViewType(position)) {
            VIEW_TYPE_EMPTY -> {
                // We are not putting any data into the empty view, therefore we do not need to do anything here
            }
            VIEW_TYPE_NOT_EMPTY -> {
                if (list != null && lessonsList != null) {
                    val subject = list[position]
                    val days = arrayListOf<Int>()
                    for (lesson in lessonsList) {
                        if (lesson.subjectId == subject.id) {
                            days.add(lesson.day)
                        }
                    }
                    holder.bind(subject, days, listener)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        val list = subjectsList
        return if (list == null || list.size == 0) 1 else list.size
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        val list = subjectsList
        return if (list == null || list.size == 0) VIEW_TYPE_EMPTY else VIEW_TYPE_NOT_EMPTY
    }

    /**
     * Swap in a new [ArrayList], containing [Subject] objects
     *
     * @param newList New list containing subjects
     * @return Returns the previously used list, or null if there wasn't one
     */
    fun swapSubjectsList(newList: ArrayList<Subject>?): ArrayList<Subject>? {
        if (newList === subjectsList) {
            return null
        }
        val numItems = itemCount
        val oldList = subjectsList
        subjectsList = newList
        if (newList != null) {
            //notify the observers
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        } else {
            //notify the observers about the lack of a data set
            notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, numItems)
        }
        return oldList
    }

    /**
     * Swap in a new [ArrayList], containing [Lesson] objects
     *
     * @param newList New list containing lessons
     * @return Returns the previously set list, or null if there wasn't one
     */
    fun swapLessonsList(newList: ArrayList<Lesson>?): ArrayList<Lesson>? {
        if (newList === lessonsList) {
            return null
        }
        val list = lessonsList
        val numItems = if (list == null || list.size == 0) 0 else list.size
        val oldList = lessonsList
        lessonsList = newList
        if (newList != null) {
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        } else {
            //notify the observers about the lack of a data set
            notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, numItems)
        }
        return oldList
    }

    open class ViewHolder(override val containerView: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(containerView), LayoutContainer {
        open fun bind(
            subject: Subject,
            days: ArrayList<Int>,
            listener: OnSubjectClickListener
        ) {
        }
    }

    private class SubjectViewHolder(override val containerView: View) : ViewHolder(containerView) {

        override fun bind(
            subject: Subject,
            days: ArrayList<Int>,
            listener: OnSubjectClickListener
        ) {
            containerView.sli_name.text = subject.name
            for (day in days) {
                when (day) {
                    1 -> {
                        containerView.sli_sunday.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.has_lesson_on_day)
                        containerView.sli_sunday.setTextColor(
                            ContextCompat.getColor(
                                containerView.context,
                                R.color.colorBackgroundPrimary
                            )
                        )
                    }
                    2 -> {
                        containerView.sli_monday.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.has_lesson_on_day)
                        containerView.sli_monday.setTextColor(
                            ContextCompat.getColor(
                                containerView.context,
                                R.color.colorBackgroundPrimary
                            )
                        )
                    }
                    3 -> {
                        containerView.sli_tuesday.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.has_lesson_on_day)
                        containerView.sli_tuesday.setTextColor(
                            ContextCompat.getColor(
                                containerView.context,
                                R.color.colorBackgroundPrimary
                            )
                        )
                    }
                    4 -> {
                        containerView.sli_wednesday.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.has_lesson_on_day)
                        containerView.sli_wednesday.setTextColor(
                            ContextCompat.getColor(
                                containerView.context,
                                R.color.colorBackgroundPrimary
                            )
                        )
                    }
                    5 -> {
                        containerView.sli_thursday.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.has_lesson_on_day)
                        containerView.sli_thursday.setTextColor(
                            ContextCompat.getColor(
                                containerView.context,
                                R.color.colorBackgroundPrimary
                            )
                        )
                    }
                    6 -> {
                        containerView.sli_friday.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.has_lesson_on_day)
                        containerView.sli_friday.setTextColor(
                            ContextCompat.getColor(
                                containerView.context,
                                R.color.colorBackgroundPrimary
                            )
                        )
                    }
                    7 -> {
                        containerView.sli_saturday.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.has_lesson_on_day)
                        containerView.sli_saturday.setTextColor(
                            ContextCompat.getColor(
                                containerView.context,
                                R.color.colorBackgroundPrimary
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
            }

            containerView.sli_linearlayout.setOnClickListener {
                listener.onSubjectClick(subject)
            }
        }

    }

    // We do not need to override the bind method since we're not putting any data into the empty view
    private class EmptySubjectViewHolder(override val containerView: View) :
        ViewHolder(containerView)
}
```

Comment: Looks like that you are setting "filled" days in the `VIewHolder`, but not resetting them, so when the `View` gets reused, filled days stay filled (and new ones are being added on top of these). 
You can try and "unfill" the days that shouldn't be filled for the subject in the `bind()` of your `ViewHolder`.

Comment: @MikhailOlshanski This seems to have solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is seem to be Recycler Views are not getting cleaned before reuse them.
you must clear/reset your days color.. e.g here

```
 containerView.sli_name.text = subject.name
  <HERE CLEAR/RESET YOUR DAYS COLOR FOR ALL THE 7 DAYS>
 for (day in days) {
                when (day) { ... }
```

Comment: @MikhailOlshanski and your suggestion solved my problem! However, this didn't seem to be a problem in previous builds. I didn't reset the view, but it's also possible that I just wasn't paying enough attention, and somehow it went over my head. I'll definitely need to do some more testing with previous versions! Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I  think you have to use database here if user enter two subjects you have to save local database next time he opens fragment he can see saved subjects